# Why is Hinata's hair short?

Tags: naruto

In Part One, Hinata cuts her hair short and it makes her look hair look like a duck's tail (sorry, Hinata). She lets it grow long in Part Two, the cuts it short again in Part Three. There may not be any reason why she does so, but can someone tell me why Hinata cuts her hair short (if there even is any reason)?

Comment: i'm not sure how far ahead it was planned but Hinata having shorter hair makes her look different from her sister Hanabi initally

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I heard someone say that Sasuke likes girls with long hair. Because Hinata has a crush on Naruto, she wants to keep her hair short so that Sasuke won't like her, is he ever does.

The other reason is that the tradition in Japan is that girls have their hair cut short if they are a disgrace to their clan/family. Hinata was not very strong at Part One, as she was defeated by her little sister Hanabi, though she was 5 years younger. Hiyashi Hyuga, Hinata's dad, even referred to her as a disgrace (in one of the filler episodes).

Comment: I heard this and that in old Asia, when you were a disgrace to your family, they cut your hair short to show you are an embarrassment. So Hinata's hair was short, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I ***genuinely*** doubt that this is even an accurate answer.  I ***genuinely*** doubt that Hinata's choice in hair style had anything to do at all with Sasuke.  If you're going to stick to this assertion, I want to see sources to prove this.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan an accepted answer is marked by the Asker, one person while the -1 score is the total of +2/-3, 5 people. also you can see in the [timeline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/39951/timeline) that the accept vote came 10 minutes after the answer was posted and personally i wouldn't have done so in the state it was in at the time

Comment: I know how scoring is performed. But this was seriously the first time in a few years on stack where I saw an accepted answer with negative score

Comment: Nice uselees answer and is accepted, "in one chapter, i hear someone say" the better reason of the year...

Answer (score 4):

I think it's just a device to show aging. In part one, she is a kid and has short hair, in part two, she is a teen and has long hair, and in part, three she is an adult and has short hair again.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because on ancient Asia (Japan, China, Korea and probably some other Ancient cultures) symbolizes being banished or rejected from there home, Hinata cuts her hair short because of the reason on how she has been rejected from her father Hiashi Hyuga.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source on that?

Answer (score -2):

girls cut their hair short in asia
Many women today maintain long hair when they're single, and then cut it shorter when they have kids, due to its impracticality. So in a way, that cutting of hair is a ceremony that mirrors that of an Edo period Samurai: an end to an era of someone's life, and the beginning of another.

and we do know that the series naruto is based on shinobi's / ninjas who existed during the edo period so this is a proof that this answer is related.

Comment: There is so much in here that is based on hearsay and assumption, and nothing here is based in fact.  If you have sources to back your claim up, sure, provide them, but be sure to somehow also tie this to the Naruto world.

Comment: "Many women today maintain long hair when they're single, and then cut it shorter when they have kids" Personally I've never seen such women that does things like this (at least) in Japan (3/4 of my woman friends maintain long(ish) hair while others being short hair for all the way)... I don't know about other countries though.